# JCarousel doesn't display correctly when adding struts2-jquery-plugin tag declaration

Tags: jquery, plugins, struts2, jcarousel

I'm using struts2 jquery plugin 2.5.1 and jcarousel 0.2.7.

The JCarousel works properly but as soon as I add `<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>` it fails to render properly and is just displayed as a list of UL LI's.

I'm guessing it might be some sort of collision between the struts2 jquery plugin and the `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>` definition needed for the JCarousel but I have no clue.

Anyone can suggest anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the S2 jquery plugin.

Instead look for a template solution although it seems more complicated at first.  A good template system will reduce a lot of work for larger sites and pay it self off. Then apply unobtrusive javascript/jquery to your work. Apache Tiles2 and Sitemesh are popular, I use Tiles.

The S2 Dojo tags have been deprecated, not because of a short coming in dojo but because of a short coming in ajax tag libraries. They add an extra level of abstraction to a component making it more brittle. If you need to provide a JS function as an argument they force the mixing of JS within the JSP (intrusive). They are going to lag behind and provide a small subset of all the components that are out there.

When a tag lib does what you need it to, it might be a faster solution... and only very slightly so because they are just very thin wrapper over jquery plug-ins but once you need it to do something more you'd have been better off with straight jQuery.